# How to update Sub Window on view-model's properties changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm learning wpf now, but there a problem when coding . The play data were get from MainWindow,and show player's ID,Name....But i need update player's information. SubWindowViewModel side ,I have update binding properties ,but there is problem, I can't update properties in the view side .I want to update SubWindow when viewModel's properties changed .

```
public SubWindow(Player player)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ISubWindowViewModel subWindowViewModel = new SubWindowViewModel();
        #region Get data
        subWindowViewModel.ID = player.ID;
        subWindowViewModel.Name = player.Name;
        subWindowViewModel.Sex = player.Sex;
        #endregion
        this.DataContext = subWindowViewModel;
    }
```

and view model has implement INotifyPropertyChanged,in xaml.cs:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding UserName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Sex" Text="{Binding Sex,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="ID" Text="{Binding ID,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have any guesses about what your viewmodel code might be?

Comment: sorry, there are some error code.I'm not sure whether it caused by  ISubWindowViewModel SubWindowViewModel = new SubWindowViewModel(); where SubWindowViewModel using INotifyPropertyChanged. So may be the problem is ISubWindowViewModel didn't inherit INotifyPropertyChanged?sorry , I'm new to wpf ,thank you

Comment: Have u called OnPropertyChanged() method when a property is set..??
And u can provide some more code involving all of this updating part with mainWindow,  viewModel class and others. So, we all could be more clarified.

Comment: Hi, I have provided some codes that i think that could help or give u some hints about the problem. You can try it.

Comment: Thank you.@Mr. Top Thank you , I implement it yet .The weird thing is if the value of  ID or Name set string.Empty in viewmodel...the textBox of Wpf window  change into null.So , I guess the problem is what have ignored——Some code like this I use in viewmodel :private System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;   syncContext.Post(new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(OnBroadcast), player);  So May be it cause by UI thread and  INotifyPropertyChanged.I will charify it ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not pro.. coder too.

What I think is you have to implement something called **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface in the **viewmodel** class.

> Check out the link. There could be more link out there.

[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx)

[INotifyPropertyChanged Interface in WPF with Example](http://aspdotnet-sekhar.blogspot.com/2013/08/INotifyPropertyChanged-in-wpf.html)

Learn and implement it. Hope it helps. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I am assuming your viewModelClass name as **PersonViewModel**. So your viewmodel class would be sth. like below.

```
class PersonViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _username;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { 
            _username= value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
        }
    }
}
```

Your xaml is correct. So now I am assuming that you have passed the same **viewmodelclass** *object*(in the constructor) that u have used in the MainWindow. So in the code behind you have to set the DataContext of the window as u have done above.

```
public SubWindow(PlayerViewModel player)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext=player;
}
```

Comment: That should really be a comment, not answer.

Comment: however,Thank you，INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the viewmodel class is implement in viewmodel ,but may be it caused by In view ,I used ISubWindowViewModel SubWindowViewModel = new SubWindowViewModel(); Is there any advise?thanks